# Attaching Boolean Values to Rect for Comparison

Tags: java, android

I have three buttons that returns true or false depending on if they are pressed down or not. I also have an Arraylist of rectangles that I want to assign specific Boolean values to. I have another separate rectangle that crosses the screen and interests my arraylist of rectangles. When it intersects, I want it to compare the set Boolean values to what the buttons return. I am not sure how to do this and so far am thinking something along the lines of this:

```
rectangles.get(0) = rectangles.add(new Rect(xCoor, yCoor, rectW, rectH));
             setFinger(rectangles.get(0), true, true, false);

for (Rect rect : rectangles) {
         if (bar.intersect(rect)) {
             checkButtons();
             Log.d("GameScreen", "Note and Bar Intersected");

         }

     }

private void setFinger (Rect rect, boolean F1, boolean F2, boolean F3) extends Rect {


}

private void checkButtons() {
  for (int t = 0; t<500; t++) {
      Rect Rec_Integer = rectangles.get(t);
      Log.i("GameScreen", Rec_Integer.toString());

    checkBoolean(Rec_Integer);
  }
}

private void checkBoolean(Rect rect) {
if (rect.getCorrectFinger() == rect.getUserFinger) {
    playCorrectSound();
}   
if (rect.getCorrectFinger() != rect.getUserFinger) {
    playIncorrectSound();
}

private void getUserFinger() {
    if (B1Pressed) {

}

}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a separate class to store your information?

```
class RectInfo() {
    private Rect rect;
    private boolean pressed;

    // for the constructor I'm assuming it won't be pressed on instantiation
    RectInfo(Rect rect) {
        this.rect = rect;
        pressed = false;
    }

    boolean isPressed() {
        return pressed;
    }

    void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        this.pressed = pressed;
    }

    // for fun / ease
    void toggle() {
        this.pressed = !this.pressed;
    }

    // getters/setters for rect of your choosing
}
```

So, instead of making your `rectangles` an `ArrayList<Rect>` make it an `ArrayList<RectInfo>`.

If you don't want to do this, you could probably accomplish something similar with a `Map<Rect, Boolean>`, where you could `put` or `get` the map values based on whatever conditions you want to use.